# Decompress ZIP file in isolated storage

Tags: c#, zip, isolatedstorage

I'm trying to create a small program that regularly downloads a ZIP archive (a [GTFS](https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs/) feed), extracts the files and loads the data into a database. The files should be stored in Isolated Storage.

However, I cannot find a way to extract the ZIP archive. There are [multiple built-in classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404280%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that handle decompression, but they either take directory/file names as arguments or cannot handle multiple files/directories.

What am I missing? How do we extract a ZIP file in Isolated Storage into a directory there (without using third party libraries)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the zip archive and enumerate all the entries. Open each entry which gives you a stream then copy the content of that entry to an isolated storage stream:

```
using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(zipPath))
{
    foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
    {
        using (Stream zipStream = entry.Open())
        using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isoStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(entry.Name, FileMode.CreateNew, isoStore))
        {
            // copy from zipStream to isoStream
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `ZipFile.OpenRead` takes a path as argument so it wouldn't do but I found that `ZipArchive` [can be created](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh158268(v=vs.110).aspx) from a `Stream` too so it could work this way.